# Gson custom deserializer when it contains object or json string

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit

How I can I write custom deserializer for same object? Or create 2 Objects (one which contains raw json string and another - Object)?

I'm getting "all device list" from server, and "updated device list" from server. Problem is that when I getting "all device list" I'm getting "Sensor", "Services", "Tail" as objects, but when getting "updated device list" that fields comes as strings (json strings). I will add photos to clarify issue.

All devices response:

[All devices] https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/lzhJXviqtW2l0pLHkJ9-2VBck9hnmREdfTlWTMF8BYTklbXR90jDe2AZbG9sHHPynCXh3HWlFQBsFBiL_oke-AMy-79zIqUsW8HVT7CrulA_KKyItARfwbRxWm8LWBspEriJEsfT4_AgNR7uceyO9pH4VAIm9LBBcuvoFOMJmvSt-y85dgqPld3WJ0RwIlQOBv3rqiw6Ci4QOC983LpiJAKgTgshsQeGNKUWnBIbzkJr87vtF54XOf4PsdAqv3IuRczQSeNLllPTIEaz6rylCotcgANWShMcpm-hQdlrt7E0VBygGTZGLW4hoOQn2F4DWH8p-QH2pEb7JKtEopha0q5cyISbK6AQSYHKMpYb7E8I_FKoxbQIEsvvjDPwGezZlloI1r6HnRHDpAaL8a2eF3yZ3ABTORHS8fa5UY___nvE1cppgzhuK9a1pFFX_A7yZQN_zQNM58i5hW6q0MhawbfFyY8NXBtTOujxz_NIg4_qP3Eu58Eb-wwz17pxYfpAbPRiDXrQDgaXPSmOrJ_txvdzP910UcxHZqFNiW_k3DXUN2tzCY2XSuyyZgc2eX-ZWaE0tevqsvdiCJSd2OvNBC8ihmZUTT0mreyZy-ii8xi2uHjN0KCtvmAkpy-XlKU1lddoxlwj_IrZqbSH_UPdqF4sa5tEahQ=w598-h1336-no

Updated devices response:

[updated devices] https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-5VlMyTbTCmLcc14oWbaE5QViCio1V3NlcXQrrApZatE8K3CnW4flCGTbpncp_rbFnhjYq49WBqKBBD4g8TBwbHvZe1qsUZSW4JaTr1ZVJFCiLz1fl6SMredI7XnYhbm85q4-RxwxaEP90X6QAR7JOqZICk1QWTS0KxTp3XckHP45ca02LHicNO4TuB72_M1-vx4FMoAZQ42vSrnKZsHBqprJnsthS3ZoG9_v72xgjXPFRb144sRb0PPn6L9VbphZPbBhcg7WU68LK6eZgqyjIByxnkAlh-tsOLsWfMoze1Df93x9OI6OqOao8cphZD_bot-AViErtnc_vyNLHaDniJ6G6gUdDgco6rNCgyPvhGIcPbKf-wWdB8ENQ47HeJVxuJ0E9EE7rGRFhPchR1FxGM2nHewyoicds6uS2eCVpiKjtnen6TuTDfx3aH9NRUzL3thvN_9Jengh_XsyMPpvhGGHAUEcpYraHEXdtC25X9t5zpB1FhLzDiWVIZwhwihOCVI-5J-VBi7JqCOm9eaagYFunZSQI6U3u1qK1SZZfCarzxm_1dCYUECBNAUCdb_HfHM24m9-D8_R77t9DNrMPgisPtOonkqORJzTtHsz-FjyxXAHbp72urUGrHLLlZnRRsrpj4NFdLX_DuXwp5k3SiUlnWTLHk=w2214-h1312-no

[All devices model] https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/lRHdw7nVVz05dG57znq_Vzwwc9zFgEmeS_kQsrqcY2u6OOkcknrpMSytte14jOqmRH_829RAitVc3HVQL2St3g8iSh7STm9XNxuBTJkxAo9OPjbv6l02s02jT35IXWo2qhGy0hiiD4uBfAlYdyy-fjXGCAe4wMLvJYPiDUc9mY73Tf3rxRw5TJ1-XW11hyE3oeHj5OkMzET7_mMoKhro3Bs97HzdDOWO2_5QHAYeqwIuQNJ8NfjU1HTeozdOF_NuAk2nZF8YajHX_VJ4FZtOhovTltZGWJseQ2RzM3gsmd2nt5-obE3msOxPYXf3R9lYlolryRNpBFGHWOrR9xj-6QfuxIOHJOWhQAkkNEAOB7emcvvFzgSQkj0Xkoro2nZCkPH-wagSAJFm-cMhOjapdwhvvlUEjaOh9dw29RBT7jfYH5r2f7i2KELBxksG1uIVo9PcHjg0hvgC0xsw2WMLWFlDnWetngJxmyl6U8pM8NNLghm5CxFaMAKnygnN_4F0aCjfQEeBX-XaC5ss4_1fDQnifw7UcnhBH7n5VZqyYiK1jNqPYDGFJS1J8FJPkXmZsc8uOtAXIa0t58ZOrQ5jHeAKsIlrlj-eM_HP7hM9iQi0VCxjaRmonD_nc6ueKGjyj4xDm9b4uAXnO1B3krVfGAstaJ_RvHw=w552-h652-no

[updated devices model] https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/8uIPKFBfwEfGg7t_KlIB8xJrI1RPJW8WhozKIa7enNlGf7AMZqF0r8qz3FPZ6IzSlyfI3PFk6OFIskPpxzep5_cHudRK5LhpbHdsZkplM8aCoeOSO7-DG8bgTQ__-iEzpmhSG4HORmLauA80L6tEh3SJxbOPoKlconsj7cXWT2uZcPD9xYAjBYHtMp7wrOZXEeAHJPqLoonxIVPsQ-CGTmhVDjQW33YUqhUytDY1FlJcnNCRQVUTRsw5NasxwvCkDVdhFBFlDNyVXX6HN_GL-ZBLNmxrOQyxz_Q7_D7e_sGVp9iw0iQIABr4ogk-9chsY8F0iNjdrD67BxGXaExRN9Nog-TuHgDEf1uLgHUJi6TZRyoalalF-q1Rf6h3Xj3mKj56bSfgk8Z25W3fToOQBMwNEwcYIy8c4bzDjMzvS8san5XkRDIrilN7-iRwJQjH-Q43cgLeSg7wTBCFrqeRPblRCe79A1dVTEnlkHl9aPmp8aW9ih0b5yMcmJjK40BwqQu0sBplzBL_oKDeooVxQ7Yp-sAfa9XKHB-s4WiKbU5fAfURt_jsRO5JtHCeiyjVw9D2RiCZ_fbzTTZGMv4ysJNIYU9oADJLdl-zHTbGzpNggd-KxOWnoDffdHlQkH5nB_FeH11hMbkvdjpFarblpMjh_hhh5dM=w681-h763-no

Json where I'm getting Object

```
[{"id":"68","title":"testRecall","items":[{"id":992,"alarm":0,"name":"CloudMM","online":"offline","time":"2018-10-28 23:30:58","timestamp":1540806358,"acktimestamp":1540806358,"lat":0,"lng":0,"course":0,"speed":0,"altitude":0,"icon_type":"icon","icon_color":"red","icon_colors":{"moving":"green","stopped":"red","offline":"red","engine":"yellow"},"icon":{"id":10,"user_id":null,"type":"icon","order":3,"width":46,"height":64,"path":"images\/device_icons\/v2\/objects2a_38.png","by_status":"0"},"power":"-","address":"-","protocol":"osmand","driver":"-","driver_data":{"id":null,"user_id":null,"device_id":null,"name":null,"rfid":null,"phone":null,"email":null,"description":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},"sensors":[],"services":[],"tail":[],"distance_unit_hour":"kph","unit_of_distance":"km","unit_of_altitude":"mt","unit_of_capacity":"lt","stop_duration":"0h","moved_timestamp":0,"engine_status":null,"detect_engine":"gps","engine_hours":"gps","total_distance":0,"device_data":{"id":992,"user_id":70,"current_driver_id":null,"timezone_id":null,"traccar_device_id":992,"icon_id":10,"icon_colors":{"moving":"green","stopped":"red","offline":"red","engine":"yellow"},"active":1,"deleted":0,"name":"CloudMM","imei":"665544332211","fuel_measurement_id":1,"fuel_quantity":"0.00","fuel_price":"0.00","fuel_per_km":"0.00","sim_number":"","device_model":"","plate_number":"","vin":"","registration_number":"","object_owner":"","additional_notes":"","expiration_date":null,"sim_expiration_date":"0000-00-00","sim_activation_date":"0000-00-00","installation_date":"0000-00-00","tail_color":"#33cc33","tail_length":5,"engine_hours":"gps","detect_engine":"gps","min_moving_speed":6,"min_fuel_fillings":10,"min_fuel_thefts":10,"snap_to_road":0,"gprs_templates_only":0,"valid_by_avg_speed":"1","parameters":"[\"batterylevel\",\"satellites\",\"hdop\",\"sequence\",\"distance\",\"totaldistance\",\"motion\",\"valid\",\"enginehours\"]","currents":null,"created_at":"2018-10-29 05:34:27","updated_at":"2019-02-27 07:58:31","forward":{"active":"1","ip":"198.121.31.32","port":"6000","protocol":"TCP"},"stop_duration":"0h","pivot":{"user_id":70,"device_id":992,"group_id":68,"current_driver_id":null,"active":1,"timezone_id":null},"traccar":{"id":"992","name":"CloudMM","uniqueId":"665544332211","latestPosition_id":"1","lastValidLatitude":null,"lastValidLongitude":null,"other":"<info><batterylevel>23<\/batterylevel><satellites>0<\/satellites><hdop>0<\/hdop><sequence>6<\/sequence><distance>0<\/distance><totaldistance>0<\/totaldistance><motion>false<\/motion><valid>false<\/valid><enginehours>0<\/enginehours><\/info>","speed":"0.00","time":"2018-10-29 09:45:45","device_time":"2018-10-29 09:45:45","server_time":"2018-10-29 09:45:58","ack_time":"2018-10-29 09:45:58","altitude":null,"course":null,"power":null,"address":null,"protocol":"osmand","latest_positions":null,"moved_at":null},"icon":{"id":10,"user_id":null,"type":"icon","order":3,"width":46,"height":64,"path":"images\/device_icons\/v2\/objects2a_38.png","by_status":"0"},"sensors":[],"services":[],"driver":null,"users":[{"id":70,"email":"tomas@gpswox.com"}],"lastValidLatitude":0,"lastValidLongitude":0,"latest_positions":null,"icon_type":"icon","group_id":68,"user_timezone_id":null,"time":"2018-10-29 09:45:45","course":0,"speed":0}},{"id":1099,"alarm":0,"name":"testRecalObject","online":"offline","time":"Not connected","timestamp":0,"acktimestamp":0,"lat":0,"lng":0,"course":0,"speed":0,"altitude":0,"icon_type":"arrow","icon_color":"red","icon_colors":{"moving":"green","stopped":"yellow","offline":"red","engine":"yellow"},"icon":{"id":0,"user_id":null,"type":"arrow","order":1,"width":25,"height":33,"path":"assets\/images\/arrow-ack.png","by_status":"0"},"power":"-","address":"-","protocol":"-","driver":"-","driver_data":{"id":null,"user_id":null,"device_id":null,"name":null,"rfid":null,"phone":null,"email":null,"description":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},"sensors":[],"services":[],"tail":[],"distance_unit_hour":"kph","unit_of_distance":"km","unit_of_altitude":"mt","unit_of_capacity":"lt","stop_duration":"0h","moved_timestamp":0,"engine_status":null,"detect_engine":"gps","engine_hours":"gps","total_distance":0,"device_data":{"id":1099,"user_id":70,"current_driver_id":null,"timezone_id":null,"traccar_device_id":1099,"icon_id":0,"icon_colors":{"moving":"green","stopped":"yellow","offline":"red","engine":"yellow"},"active":1,"deleted":0,"name":"testRecalObject","imei":"oooopaaa","fuel_measurement_id":1,"fuel_quantity":"0.00","fuel_price":"0.00","fuel_per_km":"0.00","sim_number":"","device_model":"","plate_number":"","vin":"","registration_number":"","object_owner":"","additional_notes":"","expiration_date":null,"sim_expiration_date":"0000-00-00","sim_activation_date":"0000-00-00","installation_date":"0000-00-00","tail_color":"#63f542","tail_length":0,"engine_hours":"gps","detect_engine":"gps","min_moving_speed":1,"min_fuel_fillings":1,"min_fuel_thefts":1,"snap_to_road":0,"gprs_templates_only":0,"valid_by_avg_speed":"1","parameters":null,"currents":null,"created_at":"2019-07-20 21:46:11","updated_at":"2019-07-20 21:46:11","forward":null,"stop_duration":"0h","pivot":{"user_id":70,"device_id":1099,"group_id":68,"current_driver_id":null,"active":1,"timezone_id":null},"traccar":{"id":"1099","name":"testRecalObject","uniqueId":"oooopaaa","latestPosition_id":null,"lastValidLatitude":null,"lastValidLongitude":null,"other":null,"speed":null,"time":null,"device_time":null,"server_time":null,"ack_time":null,"altitude":null,"course":null,"power":null,"address":null,"protocol":null,"latest_positions":null,"moved_at":null},"icon":{"id":0,"user_id":null,"type":"arrow","order":1,"width":25,"height":33,"path":"assets\/images\/arrow-ack.png","by_status":"0"},"sensors":[],"services":[],"driver":null,"users":[{"id":70,"email":"tomas@gpswox.com"}],"lastValidLatitude":0,"lastValidLongitude":0,"latest_positions":null,"icon_type":"arrow","group_id":68,"user_timezone_id":null,"time":null,"course":0,"speed":0}}]}]
```

And where I'm getting String

```
{"items":[{"id":124,"alarm":0,"name":"Demo 1","online":"ack","time":"2019-08-22 03:26:02","timestamp":1566481263,"acktimestamp":0,"lat":55.675715,"lng":12.576404,"course":37,"speed":0,"altitude":1,"icon_type":"icon","icon_color":"yellow","icon_colors":{"moving":"green","stopped":"yellow","offline":"red","engine":"yellow"},"icon":{"id":3,"user_id":null,"type":"icon","order":3,"width":46,"height":64,"path":"images/device_icons/v2/objects2a_63_ack.png","by_status":"1"},"power":"-","address":"-","protocol":"homtecs","driver":"Testing","driver_data":{"id":"3","user_id":"1","device_id":"128","device_port":null,"name":"Testing","rfid":"ABC451132","phone":"4","email":"","description":"","created_at":"2017-06-20 19:00:43","updated_at":"2018-10-22 14:38:51"},"sensors":"[{\"id\":\"299\",\"type\":\"satellites\",\"name\":\"Satellites\",\"show_in_popup\":\"0\",\"value\":\"8\",\"val\":\"8\",\"scale_value\":null},{\"id\":\"300\",\"type\":\"satellites\",\"name\":\"Accuracy\",\"show_in_popup\":\"0\",\"value\":\"1.02\",\"val\":\"1.02\",\"scale_value\":null}]","services":"[{\"id\":\"9\",\"name\":\"Service one\",\"value\":\"Days Left (28d.)\",\"expiring\":false},{\"id\":\"19\",\"name\":\"Ignas\",\"value\":\"\\\"Sensor\\\" was not found.\",\"expiring\":true},{\"id\":\"20\",\"name\":\"Ignas w\",\"value\":\"Days Left (1560d.)\",\"expiring\":false},{\"id\":\"21\",\"name\":\"Poiu\",\"value\":\"\\\"Sensor\\\" was not found.\",\"expiring\":true}]","tail":"[{\"lat\":\"55.675024666667\",\"lng\":\"12.5744815\"},{\"lat\":\"55.675158166667\",\"lng\":\"12.574806833333\"},{\"lat\":\"55.675362333333\",\"lng\":\"12.575193666667\"},{\"lat\":\"55.675581666667\",\"lng\":\"12.575788833333\"},{\"lat\":\"55.675698666667\",\"lng\":\"12.5761065\"}]","distance_unit_hour":"kph","unit_of_distance":"km","unit_of_altitude":"mt","unit_of_capacity":"lt","stop_duration":"1min 42s","moved_timestamp":1566481160,"engine_status":null,"detect_engine":"gps","engine_hours":"gps","total_distance":7088342.97,"device_data":{"id":124,"user_id":70,"current_driver_id":3,"timezone_id":null,"traccar_device_id":124,"icon_id":3,"icon_colors":{"moving":"green","stopped":"yellow","offline":"red","engine":"yellow"},"active":1,"deleted":0,"name":"Demo 1","imei":"100000001","fuel_measurement_id":1,"fuel_quantity":"0.00","fuel_price":"0.00","fuel_per_km":"0.00","sim_number":"","device_model":"","plate_number":"","vin":"","registration_number":"","object_owner":"","additional_notes":"","expiration_date":null,"sim_expiration_date":"0000-00-00","sim_activation_date":"0000-00-00","installation_date":"0000-00-00","tail_color":"#33cc33","tail_length":5,"engine_hours":"gps","detect_engine":"gps","min_moving_speed":6,"min_fuel_fillings":10,"min_fuel_thefts":10,"snap_to_road":0,"gprs_templates_only":0,"valid_by_avg_speed":"1","parameters":"[\"sat\",\"hdop\",\"valid\",\"enginehours\",\"rfid\"]","currents":{"geofences":[]},"created_at":"2017-07-04 08:13:53","updated_at":"2018-12-20 08:10:59","forward":null,"stop_duration":"1min 42s","pivot":{"user_id":70,"device_id":124,"group_id":71,"current_driver_id":3,"active":1,"timezone_id":null},"traccar":{"id":"124","name":"Demo 1","uniqueId":"100000001","latestPosition_id":"9275412","lastValidLatitude":"55.675714833333","lastValidLongitude":"12.576404333333","other":"<info><sat>8</sat><hdop>1.02</hdop><valid>true</valid><enginehours>8862443</enginehours><distance>0.46</distance><totaldistance>7088342.97</totaldistance></info>","speed":"0.06","time":"2019-08-22 13:41:02","device_time":"2019-08-22 13:41:02","server_time":"2019-08-22 13:41:03","ack_time":null,"altitude":"1.4","course":"36.8","power":null,"address":null,"protocol":"homtecs","latest_positions":"55.675698666667/12.5761065;55.675581666667/12.575788833333;55.675362333333/12.575193666667;55.675158166667/12.574806833333;55.675024666667/12.5744815;55.6749245/12.574212666667;55.674809333333/12.5739365;55.674687833333/12.5736325;55.674487333333/12.5731665;55.674489666667/12.572678;55.67469/12.5724915;55.6748885/12.572210333333;55.675289/12.571647333333;55.675530666667/12.5713325;55.6757135/12.571215666667","moved_at":"2019-08-22 13:39:20"},"icon":{"id":3,"user_id":null,"type":"icon","order":3,"width":46,"height":64,"path":"images/device_icons/v2/objects2a_63_online.png","by_status":"1"},"sensors":[{"id":"299","user_id":"1","device_id":"124","name":"Satellites","type":"satellites","tag_name":"sat","add_to_history":"0","on_value":null,"off_value":null,"shown_value_by":null,"fuel_tank_name":null,"full_tank":null,"full_tank_value":null,"min_value":null,"max_value":null,"formula":null,"odometer_value_by":null,"odometer_value":null,"odometer_value_unit":"km","temperature_max":null,"temperature_max_value":null,"temperature_min":null,"temperature_min_value":null,"value":"10","value_formula":"0","show_in_popup":"0","unit_of_measurement":"","on_tag_value":null,"off_tag_value":null,"on_type":null,"off_type":null,"calibrations":null,"skip_calibration":null},{"id":"300","user_id":"1","device_id":"124","name":"Accuracy","type":"satellites","tag_name":"hdop","add_to_history":"0","on_value":null,"off_value":null,"shown_value_by":null,"fuel_tank_name":null,"full_tank":null,"full_tank_value":null,"min_value":null,"max_value":null,"formula":null,"odometer_value_by":null,"odometer_value":null,"odometer_value_unit":"km","temperature_max":null,"temperature_max_value":null,"temperature_min":null,"temperature_min_value":null,"value":"0.87","value_formula":"0","show_in_popup":"0","unit_of_measurement":"","on_tag_value":null,"off_tag_value":null,"on_type":null,"off_type":null,"calibrations":null,"skip_calibration":null}],"services":[{"id":"9","user_id":"1","device_id":"124","name":"Service one","expiration_by":"days","interval":"30","last_service":"2019-08-20","trigger_event_left":"5","renew_after_expiration":"1","expires":"0","expires_date":"2019-09-19","remind":"0","remind_date":"2019-09-14","event_sent":"0","expired":"0","email":"","mobile_phone":""},{"id":"19","user_id":"1","device_id":"124","name":"Ignas","expiration_by":"odometer","interval":"123456","last_service":"0","trigger_event_left":"0","renew_after_expiration":"0","expires":"123456","expires_date":null,"remind":"123456","remind_date":null,"event_sent":"0","expired":"0","email":"","mobile_phone":""},{"id":"20","user_id":"1","device_id":"124","name":"Ignas w","expiration_by":"days","interval":"2000","last_service":null,"trigger_event_left":"0","renew_after_expiration":"0","expires":"0","expires_date":"2023-11-29","remind":"0","remind_date":"1970-01-01","event_sent":"1","expired":"0","email":"","mobile_phone":""},{"id":"21","user_id":"1","device_id":"124","name":"Poiu","expiration_by":"odometer","interval":"12","last_service":"0","trigger_event_left":"0","renew_after_expiration":"0","expires":"12","expires_date":null,"remind":"12","remind_date":null,"event_sent":"0","expired":"0","email":"","mobile_phone":""}],"driver":{"id":"3","user_id":"1","device_id":"128","device_port":null,"name":"Testing","rfid":"ABC451132","phone":"4","email":"","description":"","created_at":"2017-06-20 19:00:43","updated_at":"2018-10-22 14:38:51"},"lastValidLatitude":55.675715,"lastValidLongitude":12.576404,"latest_positions":"55.675698666667/12.5761065;55.675581666667/12.575788833333;55.675362333333/12.575193666667;55.675158166667/12.574806833333;55.675024666667/12.5744815;55.6749245/12.574212666667;55.674809333333/12.5739365;55.674687833333/12.5736325;55.674487333333/12.5731665;55.674489666667/12.572678;55.67469/12.5724915;55.6748885/12.572210333333;55.675289/12.571647333333;55.675530666667/12.5713325;55.6757135/12.571215666667","icon_type":"icon","group_id":71,"user_timezone_id":null,"time":"2019-08-22 13:41:02","course":37,"speed":0}}],"events":[],"time":1566481263,"version":"3.4.3.1"}
```

Comment: It would be better to paste the responses into the question. It make it easier for people to help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is just proof-of-concept but I think that you'll get the idea.

```
import com.google.gson.*
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
import java.lang.reflect.Type

data class Test(val sensors: List<Sensor>)

data class Sensor(val id: Int, val name: String)

class TestDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<Test> {
    override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement, typeOfT: Type?, context: JsonDeserializationContext): Test {
        val jsonObject = json.asJsonObject
        val sensorsJson = jsonObject["sensors"]
        val sensors = if (sensorsJson.isJsonArray) {
            sensorsJson.asJsonArray.map { context.deserialize<Sensor>(it, Sensor::class.java) }
        } else {
            val typeToken = TypeToken.getParameterized(List::class.java, Sensor::class.java)
            val sensorsElement = JsonParser().parse(sensorsJson.asString)
            context.deserialize(sensorsElement, typeToken.type)
        }
        return Test(sensors)
    }
}

fun main() {
    val gson = GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(Test::class.java, TestDeserializer())
        .create()

    val jsonWithObjects = """
{
  "sensors": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "test 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "test 2"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "test 3"
    }
  ]
}
    """.trimIndent()

    val test1 = gson.fromJson(jsonWithObjects, Test::class.java)

    val jsonWithStrings = """
{
  "sensors": "[{\"id\": 1,\"name\": \"test 1\"},{\"id\": 2,\"name\": \"test 2\"},{\"id\": 3,\"name\": \"test 3\"}]"
}
    """.trimIndent()

    val test2 = gson.fromJson(jsonWithStrings, Test::class.java)
    println(test1 == test2) // prints true
}
```